# Facebook API timeouts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, timeout, facebook-fql

Like lots of people my apps are affected by timeouts from `connect()`, `fql` and other apis.
It started on Wednesday 16, 08:00 UTC+00.
It is still unresolved.
Any official comment on this problem ?
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182705755149358

```
2011/11/17 13:38 UTC+01
IsFan
The operation has timed out

2011/11/17 13:05 UTC+01
Fql
The operation has timed out

2011/11/17 12:33 UTC+01
IsFan
The operation has timed out

2011/11/17 07:33 UTC+01
IsVerified
The operation has timed out

...

2011/11/16 21:59 UTC+01
CloseSession
The operation has timed out

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook officials responded to the facebook thread that they fixed the problem, and it is gone.